# need to help to find time difference which is more than 6 hours in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table which has two columns like: start_date and end_date.

sample value of start_time/end_time= 9/24/2019 12:22:43 AM.

now i need to write a query which will throw the data where time_interval(end_date-start_date) is more than 6 hours.

Comment: What is the data type of both columns ?

Answer (score 4):

Use an `INTERVAL` literal:

```sql
WHERE end_date > start_date + INTERVAL '6' HOUR
```

Use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function:

```sql
WHERE end_date > start_date + NUMTODSINTERVAL( 6, 'HOUR' );
```

Or use fractions of a day:

```sql
WHERE end_date > start_date + 6 / 24;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
WHERE end_date-start_date > 0.25 --(which is 1 / 24 * 6)
```